# jQuery Button handling based on a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i want to write a function which handles all buttons with a specific class.
 Each Button should have a different action, called by the function. How do i submit the specific button to my function without having to call that function right in my html markup via onclick?

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="menu" class="center">
   <ul class="menu-list center">
       <li><input type="button" value="Gruppe A" class="menu-button"></li>
       <li><input type="button" value="Gruppe B" class="menu-button"></li>
       <li><input type="button" value="Gruppe C" class="menu-button"></li>
   </ul>
</div>

$('.menu-button').click(function() {
    // here i want to check which button was clicked, for example by an ID.
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this` to get `DOM` object or `$(this)` to get jQuery object, You can also use `event.target` to get `DOM` object for source of event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dJ6K/1/)**

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(event){
   alert(event.target.value); 
   alert(this.value);
   alert($(this).val());
});​
```

Comment: Or, instead of `event.target`, just use `this`.

Comment: No problem.
All(?) options in 1 answer --> +1.

Comment: Many thanks, exactly what i was looking for. As a side question:

As i have many different choices, which i would have to handle with a lot of switch-cases, would you recommend any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I thinking you will have to use some branching construct ideally switch. One thing I would recommend to put the common opertion if any outside swich and combin switch cases for common functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the event handler, `this` will refer to the element that has been clicked. You can interact with it like you would any element. If it has an ID, you can access its `id` property:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
});
```

Note that `this` refers to a DOM node, *not* a jQuery object.

**Side note**

It would be much more efficient to delegate your event handler higher up the DOM tree. You can use the `.on()` method to do that:

```
$("#menu").on("click", ".menu-button", function () {
    // Do stuff
});
```

By doing this you only have a single copy of the event handler function in memory. By binding it to every element with the class `.menu-button`, you have a copy for each element.

Delegating the event handler works because most DOM events bubble up the tree from the element on which they originate. When the event reaches `#menu`, jQuery checks to see if it originated on an element matching the selector passed in as the 2nd argument. If it does, then the handler is executed.

Comment: To elaborate on the DOM node vs jQuery object: `$(this)` is the jQuery object for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. May i ask why your side note is declared as "more  efficent"?

Comment: @Sprottenwels - You're welcome. I've updated my answer with some more detail about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the button's value like this:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
    var value = this.value; // "Gruppe A" (Or B / C)
});
```

Since `this` refers to the DOM element that the event was activated on/from, you can access the element like you would any other DOM element.

You could then use a `switch` to select the right button:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function () {
    switch (this.value) {
        case 'Gruppe A':
            // Do something for button 1
            break;
        case 'Gruppe B':
            // Do something for button 2
            break;
        default:
            console.error('This button has not yet been implemented:', this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1/ You can access to the clicked item with `$(this)`. And do lot of 'if/else' to find which item is clicked. (not the best solution)

2/ You can add `.click` with a better selector like `$('#your-id.menu-button').click()`
this way you will avoid to do a lot of if/else statement to find which element has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Or `var currentId = this.id;`. No need to use all the jQuery wrapping in there if you're only getting the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This will do `if you have stactic buttons` in your dom:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

and this will work `if you have dynamically generated button list`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-button', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Don't use the jQuery wrapper when you're only getting a element's `id` / `value` etc. Use `this.value` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking the button class, replace for ID with:

```
if(button.attr('id) == 'something')
```

or for the current value of the button:

```
if(button.val() == 'something')
```

..

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(ev) {

  var button = $(this);

  if(button.hasClass('someclassA')) {

  }
  else if(button.hasClass('someclassB')) {

  }
  else {

  }

  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')) ;
});​
```

Comment: Exactly the same has been answered already, the same comment applies here:
Don't use the jQuery wrapper when you're only getting a element's `id` / `value` etc. Use `this.id` instead.